# Sending a form based on URL string variables

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms

Does anyone know if I can use a different method of calling the page other than:

```
window.location.replace("step2.php?cat="+index+"&state="+current_state);
```

I really want to do a form submit, preferably using jQuery,   eg:

```
javascript:document.ctl.H05.value='311';
document.ctl.cat="+index+";
document.ctl.state="+current_state”;
document.ctl.submit();
```

Do you know what the syntax would be for that?

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any jQuery in there. And I think you're looking for [ajax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29); you can check out the [MDC doc page for ajax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/AJAX). jQuery has a [bunch of ajax related functions](http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/). Without more context about your application, the jQuery code to do an ajax request would be:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'step2.php',
    data: {cat: index, state: current_state}
});
```

You could also make a form submit event handler - this way when you click a submit button, the request can be made without the page refreshing:

```
$('#ctl').submit(function(){
      $.ajax({
        url: 'step2.php',
        data: {cat: index, state: current_state}
    });

    return false; //cancel default form submit action
});
```

There's also a [jQuery plugin to ajaxify form submissions](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/).

Answer (score 0):

There is a `QueryString plugin` for JQuery: http://plugins.jquery.com/project/query-object which lets you access/modify querystring in an easy way such as

```
var newUrl = $.query.set("cat", index).set("state", current_state).toString();
```